# React JS Pushing Items to Array for List

Tags: arrays, object, reactjs, jsx

I'm still getting used to react, but have seemed to run into an issue where I am unable to push my array items as text rather than objects. Right now, I have an API call that retrieves json, then stores it to a state for later use. The end goal is to generate an unordered list in the return statement, however, whenever I try to push items to my array, they come out as Objects rather than strings. How do I resolve this?

State and API Call

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            data: {}, //filled by fetch data from API
            imgData: {}, //filled by fetch image data from API
            typeData: {}, //filled by fetch types data from API
            types: {
                typesArray: []
            },
            typeDataTotal: {},
            specificTypeData: {}
        };
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        //alert('Text field value is: ' + this.state.value);
        var _this = this;
        fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + this.state.value + '/').then(function(response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);
                return;
            }
            // Examine the text in the response
            response.json().then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.sprites.front_default);
                _this.setState({data: data});
                _this.setState({imgData: data.sprites});
                _this.setState({typeData: data.types[0].type});
                _this.setState({specificTypeData: data.types}); //this is the one I want to use for keys in the array
                _this.setState({
                    typeDataTotal: Object.keys(data.types)
                });
                console.log(data.types[0].type.name); //shows item as string
                console.log(data.types[1].type.name);
                console.log(Object.keys(data.types).length);

            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        var data = this.state.data;
        var imgData = this.state.imgData;
        var typeData = this.state.typeData;
        var typeDataTotal = this.state.typeDataTotal;
        var specificTypeData = this.state.specificTypeData;
        var forms = [];

        for (var key in typeDataTotal) {
            console.log("obj." + key + " = " + specificTypeData[key].type.name);
            forms.push(<formjs data={specificTypeData[key].type.name}/>);
            console.log(forms);
        }
        return (
            <div>{forms}</div>
        );

    }
}
```

Example of output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`typeDataTotal` is an object and you are trying to iterate over it using a `for` loop and checking it's `length` property. Simple objects, such as the one you assigned to `typeDataTotal` do not have a `length` property, so your condition of `i < typeDataTotal.length` is immediately false so the loop ends there.

In order to iterate over simple objects use the [`for <key> in <object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

UPDATE1:

Let's examine your state object and its properties:

```
this.state = {
        value: '',
        data: {}, //filled by fetch data from API
        imgData: {}, //filled by fetch image data from API
        typeData: {}, //filled by fetch types data from API
        types: {
            typesArray: []
        },
        typeDataTotal: {},
        specificTypeData: {}
    };
```

We see here that:

- `this.state.value` is a `string`,
- `this.state.data` is an `object`
- `this.state.imgData` is an `object`
- `this.state.typeData` is an `object`
- `this.state.types` is an `object`
- `this.state.types.typesArray` is an `array`
- `this.state.typeDataTotal` is an `object`
- `this.state.specificTypeData` is an `object`

With these in mind:

```
_this.setState({specificTypeData: data.types}); //this is the one I want to use for keys in the array
```

This could be wrong. From the operation right above that, when you do `_this.setState({typeData: data.types[0].type});` you make me understand that `data.types` is an `array`. `specificTypeData` should be an `object` so here you just changed `specificTypeData` to point to an `array` instead of an `object`. Since you set `specificTypeData` to be an `object` when you created your state, it should remain an `object` throughout.

If `data.types` is **not** an array, then you are accessing its values wrong then, by doing `data.types[0]`. This is how you would access it's elements if it was an array, not an object.

```
_this.setState({
    typeDataTotal: Object.keys(data.types)
});
```

Here you give me to understand that `data.types` is in fact an object, so most likely, you are accessing it's properties wrong in the previous line.

```
console.log(data.types[0].type.name); //shows item as string
console.log(data.types[1].type.name);
```

Again, what is `data.types`? Is it an `object` or is it an `array`?

UPDATE2:

Forgot to mention above that when you do

```
_this.setState({
    typeDataTotal: Object.keys(data.types)
});
```

You are changing `typeDataTotal` to be an `array` while you have initially defined it as an `object`. Decide what `typeDataTotal` should be (e.g. you can set it to be an array, when you initialise your `state`, if it makes more sense than it being an `object`) and give it an appropriate value.

So, since we now know that `data.types` is an object, here's what your state looks like after you have run the code inside the `response.json().then()` callback.

You do:

```
_this.setState({data: data});
_this.setState({imgData: data.sprites});
_this.setState({typeData: data.types[0].type});
_this.setState({specificTypeData: data.types}); //this is the one I want to use for keys in the array
_this.setState({
    typeDataTotal: Object.keys(data.types)
});
```

so you end up with this state:

```
this.state = {
    value: <string>, //this was unmodified
    data: data,  //it's an <object>, should be an <object>
    imgData: data.sprites, //I don't know what data.sprites is but should be an <object>
    typeData: data.types[0].type, //It's <undefined>, should be an <object>
    types: {
        typesArray: <array> //this was unmodified
    },
    typeDataTotal: Object.keys(data.types), //It's an <array>, should be an <object>
    specificTypeData: data.types //it's an <object>, should be an <object>
};
```

So, we finally reach your `render` method, so let's see what happens there with this state:

```
render() {
    var data = this.state.data; //it's an <object>, should be an <object>
    var imgData = this.state.imgData; //I don't know what data.sprites is but should be an <object>
    var typeData = this.state.typeData; //It's <undefined>, should be an <object>
    var typeDataTotal = this.state.typeDataTotal; //It's an <array>, should be an <object>
    var specificTypeData = this.state.specificTypeData; //it's an <object>, should be an <object>
    var forms = [];

    for (var key in typeDataTotal) { // you are now iterating over an array, so key is an integer number (0, 1, 2, etc)
        console.log("obj." + key + " = " + specificTypeData[key].type.name); //specificTypeData is an object, and you are trying to access its values by doing specificTypeData[<number>] which will return undefined.
        forms.push(<formjs data={specificTypeData[key].type.name}/>); //data={undefined}
        console.log(forms);
    }
    return (
        <div>{forms}</div>
    );
}
```

What I would do if I were in your place is the following:

Turn these:

```
_this.setState({data: data});
_this.setState({imgData: data.sprites});
_this.setState({typeData: data.types[0].type});
_this.setState({specificTypeData: data.types}); //this is the one I want to use for keys in the array
_this.setState({
    typeDataTotal: Object.keys(data.types)
});
```

into

```
_this.setState({
    data: data,
    imgData: data.sprites,
    typeData: <object>,
    specificTypeData: data.types,
    typeDataTotal: <whatever you decide>
});
```

I think react is batching all your `_this.setState()` calls into one, so that you will fire `render` only once anyway, but do it this way just to be sure.

and **definitely** rethink how your state should be represented; what should be an `object` and what should be an `array`.

You will solve this eventually.

Comment: I've updated my code to the more recent version. When I console.log the object/key pairs, they're showing up as strings. However, when I try to push it into my forms array, it goes back to [Object, Object].

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed, but, what are you `return`ing exactly in your `render` method? You should be returning something there

Comment: I'm returning 
 <div>{forms}</div>

Comment: Can you please update the code in your question to reflect the code you are working with and experience problems?

Comment: So, when you do `console.log("obj." + key + " = " + specificTypeData[key].type.name);` it prints `John`, for example? Can you share the implementation of your `<formjs>` component in your question?

Comment: I've added an image of the component as well as the output, please let me know if this helps

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: When returning data.types, I get :

 [object Object]

Comment: Ok, so `data.types` is an object, so whenever you do `data.types[<number>]` this is basically wrong.

Comment: That's making a lot of sense now. No wonder I couldn't access it. What would you recommend I do to get the string that's in the object? Should I modify my for key in object loop?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: If it helped you resolve your problem do accept it as an answer, by the way. Thanks.